# How to fix the Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare Multiplayer crash on startup?

Tags: technical-issues, call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I have installed *Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare* on my Windows machine. The single player mode works perfectly, but when I try to run COD4 Multiplayer it crashes on startup. Windows then shows the following error message:

> `iw3mp.exe` has stopped working.

What can I do to fix this?

---

**Disclaimer:** I’ve made this thread to collect the various solutions to this problem that are scattered across the interwebs. Please add an answer if you have an alternative solution! All the solutions posted below have apparently fixed the problem for many people, but not for me — so I’m still looking for a solution to play CoD4 on my new gaming PC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a very common problem due to sloppy programming on Activision’s part. It is related to the system’s audio device, e.g. a problem with your sound card drivers, mostly if it is a Realtek or a Sigmatel onboard sound card.

Here are some things you can try:

### Enable Stereo Mix

1. Right-click the volume/speaker icon in your system tray, and select *Recording devices*. (If you don’t have the icon in your system tray, open *Control Panel* → *Hardware and Sound* → *Sound* → *Recording*.)
2. Right-click and select *View Disabled Devices*. The device *Stereo Mix* appears.
3. Enable the *Stereo Mix* device.
4. Start the game.

If that doesn’t solve the issue, try the next suggestion.

### Use a mic & headphones

1. Plug in a microphone into the microphone jack.
2. Plug in headphones into the headphone jack.
3. Right-click the volume/speaker icon in your system tray, and select *Recording devices*. (If you don’t have the icon in your system tray, open *Control Panel* → *Hardware and Sound* → *Sound* → *Recording*.)
4. Set *Microphone* as the default input device.
5. Switch to the *Playback* tab.
6. Set *Headphones* as the default audio playback device.
7. Start the game.

If that doesn’t solve the issue, try the next suggestion.

### Realtek: Disable front panel jack detection

If you have an Realtek onboard sound card, this might help:

1. Double-click the orange volume/speaker icon in your task bar. This opens the HD Audio Manager.
2. Click on the folder icon in the upper right edge.
3. Check *Disable front panel jack detection*. This forces the driver to load microphone support even without a mic plugged in. Close the top-most window.
4. In case you’re using the digital output, make sure that the *Digital Output* device is set as the default. To do that, click on *Digital Output* in the upper bar and on *Set Default Device* next to the volume adjuster.
5. Start the game.

If that doesn’t solve the issue, try the next suggestion.

### Sigmatel: install updates

If you have a Sigmatel onboard sound card, install all Windows updates and the latest Sigmatel drivers from http://www.dell.com/.

### Remove the `mssmp3.asi` file

1. Go to the installation folder of CoD4.
2. Enter the `miles` folder.
3. Rename the file `mssmp3.asi` to `mssmp3.asi.bak`.
4. Start the game.

If that doesn’t solve the issue, try the next suggestion.

### Update PunkBuster

Make sure PunkBuster is updated to [the latest version](http://evenbalance.com/index.php?page=pbsetup.php).

### Install Call of Duty 4 patches

Install all patches up to at least v1.5. (Currently, the latest available patch is v1.7.)

If that doesn’t solve the issue, try the next suggestion.

### Reinstall sound card drivers

Before continuing, please make note of the make and model of your sound card prior to removing it in order to aid in reinstallation at a later date.

Uninstall your sound card drivers as follows:

1. Open *Start* → *Run* and enter `sysdm.cpl` to display the *System Properties* dialog box.
2. Go to *Hardware* → *Device Manager*.
3. Expand *Sound, video, and game controllers*.
4. Right-click the sound card driver and then select *Uninstall*.

Then let Windows install its default sound drivers.

If that doesn’t solve the issue, try the next suggestion.

### Update BIOS

If you are running the game from a secondary partition, download and install the latest BIOS updates from your motherboard manufacturer.

If that doesn’t solve the issue, try the next suggestion.

### Disable onboard sound in BIOS

Disable the onboard sound card in the BIOS.

Comment: video of your first suggestion Enable Stereo Mix http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnvud9uWuYM

Comment: Very detailed answer +1 for that. "Enable Stereo Mix" part works for me. Bravo!

Comment: Great answer. I will print it out for my next LAN party

Answer (score 4):

Here are some interesting details about the unfortunate programming error that causes this bug. Credit to **Xero|Hawk** from the Infinity Ward forums for [his research on this subject](http://www.thecodforums.com/forum/showthread.php?16304).

> After looking into this a bit (as I’m affected myself), I found out
>   that the crash is caused by this piece of code (most likely a little
>   programming mistake):
>
> ```
> 004ED380  /$  51            PUSH ECX
> 004ED381  |.  6A 00         PUSH 0
> 004ED383  |.  68 78B55E0D   PUSH iw3mp.0D5EB578
> 004ED388  |.  6A 00         PUSH 0
> 004ED38A  |.  C705 D0824001>MOV DWORD PTR DS:[14082D0],iw3mp.004ED37>
> 004ED394  |.  C705 D4824001>MOV DWORD PTR DS:[14082D4],iw3mp.014082D>
> 004ED39E  |.  C605 4EB55E0D>MOV BYTE PTR DS:[D5EB54E],0
> 004ED3A5  |.  E8 1C9F1500   CALL <JMP.&DSOUND.#6>
> 004ED3AA  |.  85C0          TEST EAX,EAX
> 004ED3AC  |.  7D 14         JGE SHORT iw3mp.004ED3C2
> 004ED3AE  |.  50            PUSH EAX                                 ; /Arg3
> 004ED3AF  |.  68 A0376E00   PUSH iw3mp.006E37A0                      ; |Arg2 = 006E37A0 ASCII "Error initializing direct sound instance! %s"
> 004ED3B4  |.  6A 09         PUSH 9                                   ; |Arg1 = 00000009
> 004ED3B6  |.  E8 15F90000   CALL iw3mp.004FCCD0                      ; \iw3mp.004FCCD0 <-- crashes inside this function
> 004ED3BB  |.  83C4 0C       ADD ESP,0C
> 004ED3BE  |.  33C0          XOR EAX,EAX
> 004ED3C0  |.  59            POP ECX
> 004ED3C1  |.  C3            RETN
> 004ED3C2  |>  B8 01000000   MOV EAX,1
> 004ED3C7  |.  A2 4EB55E0D   MOV BYTE PTR DS:[D5EB54E],AL
> 004ED3CC  |.  59            POP ECX
> 004ED3CD  \.  C3            RETN
> ```
>
> `JMP.&DSOUND.#6` is a `JMP` to `DSOUND.DirectSoundCaptureCreate`, and
>   its return value is directly used for the string formatting. Most
>   likely the programmer wanted to have a formatted error message
>   displayed (which would be `DSERR_NODRIVER`), or the error value in
>   hex, or whatever, but instead he treated the return value as a string
>   pointer and because the formatting func doesnt do a `IsBadReadPtr`
>   check on it before handling it, the game crashes. I tried changing the
>   `%s` to `%X` which fixes this crash indeed, but because the
>   `DirectSoundCaptureCreate` call isnt supposed to fail, the game
>   crashes at a different position, probably when it’s trying to use the
>   interface the first time.
>
> ```
> 0057A7E2  |.  803D 4EB55E0D>|CMP BYTE PTR DS:[D5EB54E],0 <-- the IsCaptureInitialized bool, most likely
> 0057A7E9  |.  75 04         |JNZ SHORT iw3mp2.0057A7EF <-- but because the Create call failed, its not (see code snippet above),...
> 0057A7EB  |.  33F6          |XOR ESI,ESI <-- ...so make ESI zero...
> 0057A7ED  |.  EB 45         |JMP SHORT iw3mp2.0057A834 <-- ...and jump to our crashing code line (it uses ESI as pointer - very smart)
> 0057A7EF  |>  A1 D4824001   |MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[14082D4]
> 0057A7F4  |.  6A 48         |PUSH 48
> 0057A7F6  |.  8BF0          |MOV ESI,EAX
> 0057A7F8  |.  83C0 48       |ADD EAX,48
> 0057A7FB  |.  6A 00         |PUSH 0
> 0057A7FD  |.  56            |PUSH ESI
> 0057A7FE  |.  A3 D4824001   |MOV DWORD PTR DS:[14082D4],EAX
> 0057A803  |.  E8 A8890F00   |CALL iw3mp2.006731B0
> 0057A808  |.  8B0D D43E7200 |MOV ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[723ED4]
> 0057A80E  |.  83C4 0C       |ADD ESP,0C
> 0057A811  |.  C746 2C 00200>|MOV DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+2C],2000
> 0057A818  |.  C746 30 FF000>|MOV DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+30],0FF
> 0057A81F  |.  C746 34 80000>|MOV DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+34],80
> 0057A826  |.  894E 38       |MOV DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+38],ECX
> 0057A829  |.  C746 1C FFFFF>|MOV DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+1C],-1
> 0057A830  |.  C646 44 02    |MOV BYTE PTR DS:[ESI+44],2
> 0057A834  |>  8B4E 38       |MOV ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+38] <-- crashing here
> 0057A837  |.  8B46 2C       |MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+2C]
> 0057A83A  |.  8D7E 04       |LEA EDI,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+4]
> 0057A83D  |.  57            |PUSH EDI
> 0057A83E  |.  C746 08 00C80>|MOV DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+8],0C800
> 0057A845  |.  E8 7623F7FF   |CALL iw3mp2.004ECBC0
> 0057A84A  |.  83C4 04       |ADD ESP,4
> 0057A84D  |.  85C0          |TEST EAX,EAX
> 0057A84F  |.  7D 21         |JGE SHORT iw3mp2.0057A872
> 0057A851  |.  68 B8356E00   |PUSH iw3mp2.006E35B8                    ;  ASCII "Error: Failed to create DirectSound play buffer"
> 0057A856  |.  6A 09         |PUSH 9
> 0057A858  |.  E8 B323F8FF   |CALL iw3mp2.004FCC10
> ```
>
> The same mistake has been done at least one more time, namely here:
>
> ```
> 0057A94F  |.  8B11          MOV EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ECX]
> 0057A951  |.  8B42 08       MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+8]
> 0057A954  |.  51            PUSH ECX
> 0057A955  |.  FFD0          CALL EAX
> 0057A957  |.  8B35 60B55E0D MOV ESI,DWORD PTR DS:[D5EB560]
> 0057A95D  |>  3BC3          CMP EAX,EBX
> 0057A95F  |.  891D 78B55E0D MOV DWORD PTR DS:[D5EB578],EBX
> 0057A965  |.  7D 16         JGE SHORT iw3mp2.0057A97D
> 0057A967  |.  50            PUSH EAX                                 ; /Arg3
> 0057A968  |.  68 D0376E00   PUSH iw3mp2.006E37D0                     ; |Arg2 = 006E37D0 ASCII "Error releasing direct sound instance!  %s"
> 0057A96D  |.  6A 09         PUSH 9                                   ; |Arg1 = 00000009
> 0057A96F  |.  E8 5C23F8FF   CALL iw3mp2.004FCCD0                     ; \iw3mp2.004FCCD0
> ```